# "You should help John rather than he helping you."

Tags: participle-phrases

> You should help John rather than he helping you.

I sometimes see this sentence pattern. But I feel like something is missing between "he" and "helping". What is this pattern?

Edit:
I found a sentence in another forum:

Most people want fees for subsidised patients to be standardised rather than each *public hospital setting its own rates* - the way (they do now) now.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/standardised-rather-than-have-having-each-public-hospital.2829335/

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase construction is not ideal. Look up the **subjunctive form**:

> You should help John rather than he **help** you.

Using the progressive form, which suggests the action is ongoing,  is an alternative way to express the same concept:

> You should be **helping** John instead of **him helping** you.

From [Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825045104/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive) (formerly *Oxford Dictionaries*)

> 1. In *that*-clauses
>    Nowadays it [the subjunctive] is probably most frequent in *that-*clauses with verbs such as *demand*, *insist*, *pray*, *recommend*, *suggest*, and semantically related nouns/adjectives, e.g. *essential, important, insistence, proposal,* etc.

> - *She declined a seat beside Charles on the sofa. She insisted that Jane **sit** there.*
> - *It was suggested that he **wait** until the next morning.*
> - *It is important that they **be** aware of the provisions of the Act.*

> Note: In most such cases **it can be replaced by should + infinitive** or by the indicative form of the verb:
>
> - *She declined a seat beside Charles on the sofa. She insisted that Jane **sat** there*.
> - *It was suggested that he **should wait** until the next morning*.

Comment: But my teacher said "rather than he helps you" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Why is "s" not need? Is it because you omit the "should"?

Comment: @dodoll I really don't have the spare time to go into details, it seemed you were saying that I had written "he helps you" when I had not. So, to answer your most recent question: Immediately after "should" the verb is in the infinite e.g. "*He should **study***" and "*He should **be** studying*"

Comment: @dodoll  In British English "It's important *that* Bob **helps** you" is more common whereas in American English "It's important *that* Bob **help** you" is considered to be grammatically correct.

Comment: "It's important that Bob help you" is new to me. Thanks! I learn something new today. But I saw "rather than + subject + verb-ing" a few times so I wonder what sentence pattern it is.

Comment: @dodoll  Then please show the link where you saw this construction IN the question. If it's from memory you should state this.

Comment: I just found a sentence and added it in the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You use the subjunctive form after *rather*? it doesn't sound correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Most people want fees for subsidised patients to be standardised
> rather than each public hospital setting its own rates

I see this an abbreviated form of

Most people want fees for subsidised patients *to be* standardised rather than *to have* each public hospital setting its own rates